# sharepoint 2013 server requirement?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I wanted to install sharepoint and I have read [Hardware requirements—web servers, application servers, and single server installations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#hwforwebserver)

My computer specification is shown below[image]

**Does it meet the 64-bit, 4 cores requirement for a sharepoint 2013 server?** ***And does Core i5 mean that it has four cores?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. You always need to check the manufacturer's description of the processor to see how many cores it has. In this case, **your i5 process has 4 cores**. See [here](https://ark.intel.com/products/52209/Intel-Core-i5-2500-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz).

You also meet the 64-bit requirements.

However, depending on the use of your SharePoint server, **8GB RAM may not be anywhere near enough**. If you just want to do a test run/evaluate SharePoint, then 8GB RAM will do. If you want to do any more than that, then 8GB is not enough. You can barely do any development with 8GB RAM as well.

Comment: Thank your information was helpful. I have run msinfo32.exe to confirm my processor description